# One element on top of another, but centered, with text scaling, and fixed width and height?

Tags: html, css, css-position

How can I put one element on top of another, but still with fixed size? I tried this, but it doesn't restrict width and center text. When there is a lot of symbols, the text is going out of the borders.

Also, how can I scale text depending on container's width?

```css
html {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
}

.alarm {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 369;
  height: 123;
  padding: 5%;
}

.message {
  margin: 5px;
  word-break: break-all;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center; /* doesn't work */
  /* font scaling depending on the number of characters..? */
}

.message-container {
  max-width: 246px;
  max-height: 123px; /* doesn't work */
  position: absolute;
}

.video {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 369px;
  height: 123px;
}
```

```html
<div class="alarm">
  <div class="message-container">
    <div class="message">
      {name} is now following! fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="video-container">
    <!--there must have been a video-->
    <div class="video"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```